# Make a living VS Making a life

Tags: meaning

What's the difference in nuance between **making a living** and **making a life**?

Answer (score 2):

"Making a living" refers specifically to how one earns money. It may be the minimal money needed to support a basic life, or the much larger amounts needed to support a wealth or indeed opulent lifestyle. In an case "making a living" or more often "make a living" is specifically about the method of obtaining income.

> - He makes a good living as a corporate lawyer.
> - She makes a living -- barely -- as a stocker at Walmart.
> - He was making a living as a journalist, with his fiction only a sideline.
> - I was making a living, but I wasn't getting rich.

However "making a life" refers to a person's overall life experience or lifestyle, not just the financial side. it is often used with "for", and frequently with an indication of place or circumstance.

> - She now makes a life for herself and her family in rural Ohio.
> - After my initial flailing and missteps, I am ready to make a life. (or "make a life for myself".)
> - He says that he has made a good life for himself.
> - She no longer makes a good living, but rather a good life.

Answer (score 1):

*making a living* is quite a popular way to talk about a person who does something to live their life.

It's [an idiom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20a%20living):

> make a living: *to earn the money one needs to pay for housing, food, etc.*

On the other hand, *making a life* is a half-baked idiom. The correct one is:

> make a life for (oneself): *To establish or develop a career and lifestyle in which one is or feels happy, content, or successful.*

*make a living* is a **minimal** requirement you need to run your house or to live. However, *make a life..* includes *make a living* but I think it's a bit more than that. You can ***make a good life for yourself*** by working as a freelancer.

Comment: Also 'Making a life' can be a term for settling down somewhere. "I've made a life for myself here in Canada" - I've put down roots, maybe had a family, made friends etc - I have invested myself in this place. Not necessarily just about the job/career.